# Passing two objects to a TimerCallback

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to be able to affect multiple Textblock elements within my TimerCallback. At the moment, I have this:

```
t = new Timer(tc, myLabel, 0, 1000);
```

However, in tc, I'd like to do the following:

```
myLabel.Text = "ABC";
myLabel2.Text = "DEF";
```

I haven't figured out how to pass more than one object to my TimerCallback. Anytime I attempt to set a TextBlock inside my TimerCallback, I get an error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

I tried coding in an array of Objects but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DispatchTimer`.  You have to do that since it is a seperate thread.

```
     private void InitializeTimers()
            {
                DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer();
                tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                tmr.Tick += OnTimerTick;
                tmr.Start();
            }

  private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
              //do whatever you want
        }
```